# Changing the http referer in javascript

Tags: http

I have an image

```
<image src="blah.com/image.gif"/>
```

.   when the image loads, is there a way to change the http referer to X so that the src host sees the http referer of the image request coming from X?

Comment: Why? http://pseudo-flaw.net/content/web-browsers/firefox-referer-spoofing/

Comment: the only usage i find in this is loading images from remote websites which try to protect against that...

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to change the referrer of an image request load but is possible to remove the referrer.

There is a cross browser solution in Javascript, it uses Iframes created dynamically, check a [proof of concept](http://referrer-killer.googlecode.com/git/example.html) ( disclaimer: It uses a little JS lib I coded for that purpose).