# Changing the value of referrer

Tags: javascript, http-referer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manually set REFERER header in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580575/how-to-manually-set-referer-header-in-javascript)

How to change the value of `document.referrer`?

I tried this

```
<body>
<center><a href="test.php" target="_self">self</a></center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert( document.referrer);
    document.referrer="test";
    alert( document.referrer);
</script>
</body>
```

It is not working, any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580575/how-to-manually-set-referer-header-in-javascript

Comment: no you can't, due to prevent referrer spoofing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267550/changing-the-http-referer-in-javascript

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145534/javascript-document-referrer

Answer (score 9):

You can't modify the referrer directly, but you can use [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) / [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to push a new URL into the browser history (provided the URL you want to push has the same domain), then when you navigate away, the new URL will be the referrer.

Please note that manipulating the history using `pushState` adds a new history entry, but the page being viewed stays the same, and the user will have to press their browser's "Back" button twice to go back one *actual* page.

However, if you use `replaceState`, coming back from the page you want to hide the referrer from will go to the newly set URL, so make sure that whatever you replace it with somehow redirects the user back to the original page instead of sending them to a 404 or a completely different page.

Comment: Note that the `pushState` function is restricted to the same domain policy. Change the domain is not permitted.

Comment: you are a hero. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The property is read-only - which of course means you can't change it.

You can read more about it here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.referrer#Notes
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534365(v=vs.85).aspx